# multiple return statements or a "goto end;"

Tags: c++, coding-style, return, goto

What is better stylewise/readability?

I have a loop that reads input and does different things according to the input, and when an error occurs, I need a simple `return;`. Example:

```
while( get_input() )
{
    if( input == "somethingcool" )
    {
        if( !process_somethingcool() )
            return; // <-- a couple of these
    }
    //...
    else // bad input, error handling is fancier than this, but irrelevant to the question
        return;
}
return;
```

So should I replace the individual `return;`s with a `goto end;` and place a label `end:` right above the last return in the example above or not? I am not in need of "use RAII" because nothing is allocated in the `if` blocks. Both ways would be identical in all senses of the word, except for the style/readability/performance?

I would suppose performance is identical, but just to be sure: is it?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using exceptions in this case?

Comment: goto is generally a bad idea.  I've never had to use it, unless I'm working with somebody else's code.  As far as performance goes, I'm not sure, but I think the style of code is just as important these days as speed, so I would keep it as it is.

Comment: Can you show more code? Like some more ifs and what they do? Maybe there is a better, more general solution.

Comment: Let the baseless `goto`-bashing begin. Two thousand and eleven cookies for a logical argument.

Comment: I don't know if goto would be faster than if here, but most likely not. And in any case it will be quicker than the person at the prompt ;)

Comment: Feeling the need to use goto means you have poorly designed the flow of operations.  You probably need to implement more functions to separate the logic instead of procedural driven.

Comment: @Matt: I know I'm being stupid here, but I haven't "got" exceptions yet (ie I don't really understand their full potential). Currently I use a global error_status set by emit_error and emit_warning functions, and print them appropriately. I know, C-style stuff, but at least I know what's going on. Again, not really relevant to the question IMHO.

Comment: @rubenvb you should try harder to "get" exceptions

Comment: @AJG85: Sweeping generalisation win

Comment: @rubenvb It felt to me like it was relevant to your question, because I think it's the standard C++ way of handling the problem you're trying to handle, if I've understood what you want correctly. Effectively, C++ exception handling is doing what you're doing with a "goto" only with a bit more formality and extra functionality you might find useful down the line. It'll probably be more familiar to other C++ programmers, too, most of whom, in my experience, will have used exceptions a lot more than they've used goto.

Comment: (And also, as you're currently finding out, using exceptions in your code starts fewer religious wars than using `goto`. Sometimes you have to consider the possibility of leading a more peaceful life as a result of your design choices, whether technically correct or not :) )

Comment: @Tomalak Dijkstra pretty much proved the problems with `goto`.  Some people like to reason about the correctness of their code, and that's largely impossible in the presence of `goto` (or if not, could you point me to some published literature explaining how to do it).

Comment: @James: I'm not saying `goto` is "good". I'm not saying it's right here (indeed, my answer states the opposite). I'm aware that there are often good reasons not to use it; indeed, proving program correctness gets a bit problematic with unconditional jumps. What I'm averse to, however, is baseless bashing of a feature that, in the context of this question (and indeed in some other use cases), is perfectly fine.

Comment: @James: Dijkstra was discussing a completely different `goto` in completely different languages.  His paper is a historical oddity, and little more, when discussing C++.  That said, how is this question still open?

Comment: @Dennis: I must have specified the specifics specific enough to not make it as argumentative as it the general question may be. On top of that, there's a lot of background that comes up (see some of the answers) when doing these things. That said, everyone is seemingly in agreement that multiple returns are as performant as the goto+single return?

Comment: @Dennis: It's only subjective if there are no objective arguments to put forth. I think the answers and comments generally show that there are plenty of objective arguments to put forth, and thus the question itself has objective merit.

Comment: @rubenvb: I would seriously expect the performance to be identical, especially with optimisations. Both approaches do _the same thing_, in your stated example. Either way it's a micro-optimisation.

Comment: @Matt: OK, I understand. I'll see what exceptions can do to replace my error handling scheme.

Comment: @Dennis Dijkstra was not discussing a different language; he was discussing how to code in general.  He proved that only a very small number of flow control patterns should be used.  In a different language, `goto` might be acceptable, or even necessary.  C++ (and all other recent languages) provide structures such as `while` which eliminate the need for it; the useful flow control structures (those which allow reasoning about the code) are all supported directly in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C, goto is reasonable (it's used widely in the Linux kernel) as you can enhance readability with a single point of return.

For C++, because you have the possibility of anything throwing an exception, you implicitly have multiple points of return so you should always use the RAII model with multiple returns.

Comment: And this is why hundreds of thousands of C++ "programmers" sadly misuse exceptions. :(

Comment: Given the robustness of Linux, I wouldn't take their use in its kernel code as a reference.

Comment: @James: Heh, indeed. Playing with kernel code is ... interesting. There's certainly no reason to consider it an authority on programming techniques.

Comment: @James Could you expand that somewhat? Are you saying Linux is not robust? It seems pretty much so to me.

Comment: @Neil: IIRC, `truncate()` and `ftrunate()` are pretty good examples.

Comment: @Neil: Linux is becoming robust, but it's still not an OS I'd use in a critical system.  Linux just seems robust because people compare it to Windows.  (It's true that I no longer have to reboot it once a week, like I used to.)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like to keep the content of any blocks as small as possible.  One line, calling out to another function is ideal (after Bob Martin's Clean Code).

I'd go with an option you haven't proposed:

```
while(get_input()) {
    if(!process_input(input)) {
         break;
    }
}
```

Where process_input would select the appropriate `process_...` function, returning whatever that returns, or false if there is bad input.

Comment: "Personally, (after Bob Martin's Clean Code) I like to keep the content of any blocks as small as possible" - this is hardly original with the ghastly Martin.

Comment: You're right.  Even before reading CC, I liked to keep my blocks as small as possible, That was supposed to go after the next sentence (moved in edit).  It wasn't until I read CC, that I got the properly minimalist "one line" thing. (That's probably not original with him either, but that's where I got it from).

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to start a religious war?

Seriously, there are occasionally places where a goto is the best choice.  In twenty years, I've seen around 3 or 4.  Multiple returns are not necessarily evil, but if you have to repeat a lot of cleanup code then they become pretty messy.

Very often, you can refactor the code to make such a choice unnecessary.  It is hard to make specific suggestions without seeing your code, but maybe something like this:

```
void f()
{
   bool bDone=false;
   while (!bDone && get_input())
   {
      if (input == "cool")
      {
         process_cool();
         bDone = true;
      }
      else if (input == "unfinished")
      {
         process_something();
      }
      else
      {
          // error
          bDone = true;
      }
   }
}
```

A big help in refactoring is to make sure you don't have dozens of lines inside the loop.  If you have a lit of work to do, break it into functions and call a small number of functions from within the while loop.

Remember that a single function should only do one thing.

Another approach that is highly recommended is to use exceptions to handle error conditions, but it is bad style to use an exception if you have just finished processing, so this might not completely solve your problem.

If you are still confused, consider posting a more realistic chunk of code and we may be able to suggest how best to handle things.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Just return when you want to return. The C++ language can handle that, and it is the most intuitive way to write your code.

In some languages, cleanup has to be done at the use site, and so it may be a good idea to centralize the "cleanup" phase in a single block that you "goto". In C, this idiom is common.

In C++, resources are cleaned up *by themselves* in their destructors when they go out of scope. And so at the use site, *nothing* needs t obe done, and the easiest, cleanest and least error-prone solution is to just have multiple return statements.

Answer (score 1):

Style and readability would lead me to use exceptions to handle error conditions.  How is your caller to know whether your method was invoked correctly?

That said: `goto` shouldn't be used for this; `return` is the far better option.  If you need to do anything at the end of your routine, regardless of why it dropped out - then you should throw exceptions and use a `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

`return` is generally preferred to `goto`; usually, detractors of labels are unable to come up with any *actual* argument to support their dogma.<sup>1</sup>

However, your case is more clear-cut: why would you pick the `goto`? Both solutions are equivalent, except that the `goto` requires you to write `end:` just before the end of the function, taking up space and looking ugly for no reason.

Therefore, out of the two options presented, I'd recommend the `return`s. That said, I'd also recommend seriously considering the other suggestions given in responses to this question (exceptions, and limiting the "nestiness" of your conditionals).

---

<sup>1</sup> Or, if they do, it's usually something along the lines of "`goto` leaves your objects hanging", which is not true (as per 6.6/2 in [the C++0x FDIS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3290.pdf)). `goto` *does not break the RAII model*.

Comment: +1 Use of `goto` can sometimes be justified but much less so in C++ than C. I agree with your sentiments regarding dogma.

Comment: @David: Yea, granted there aren't _many_ justifiable use cases, and personally I'm not sure I've ever used it.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple return statements are actually good style and almost always produce cleaner code than trying to have  a single return point. gotos are pretty useless in C++ as (apart from their other problems) they can't jump over initialisations, which possibly forces you to initialise things away from their point of use, which is also bad style.

Comment: I don't see how that makes them useless. In fact, it just makes them safe. Nothing else in C++ can jump over initialisations either.

Comment: Learn some English. I said "pretty useless", not "completely useless", and I justified what I said.

Comment: @Neil: And I say you didn't; your claim makes no sense. Even "pretty useless" doesn't follow. And please do not get personal.

Comment: @Tomalak In the absence of a "plonk" facility on SO, I simply won't be replying to any more of your comments, and I promise not  to comment on your own questions and answers. Goodbye.

Comment: @Neil: All I asked was for clarification on your claim, which I believe to be mistaken. This site is for sharing knowledge and helping people who ask questions; I'm not sure what purpose is served by your outburst. Good luck.

Comment: @Tomalak: Neil is pointing out that `goto` in C++ has several severe drawbacks that can actually create a lot of subtle errors in your code, making it a strong code smell when it's used. It's quite unlike C in this regard, since C++ has a lot of rules WRT initialization and destruction that `goto` explicitly violates.

Comment: @Neil: That was not called for. I'm giving you -1 *just* for your treatment of Tomalak.

Comment: @greyfade Actually, I'm not pointing out that. C++ compilers are required to diagnose jumps over initialisation as errors. I'm saying that using goto will almost certainly cause you to rearrange your code in unnatural ways in order to avoid those errors.

Comment: @greyfade You might want to look at Tomalak's treatment of others.

Comment: @Neil: I have. It does not excuse yours.

Comment: @greyfade: I was _specifically_ inquiring as to how `goto`'s inability to jump over initialisations makes it "pretty useless", especially considering that no other C++ language feature can do this either. But I guess now I'll never know :(

Comment: @greyfade: To be clear, I don't disagree with you regarding `goto` _often_ being a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

The `goto End;` is nice in part because of readability but also because if you realize later there are things that need to happen before you close the function, freeing memory or releasing resources for example, you can centralize that process instead of copy pasting it.

Comment: No, in C++, the way you release resources is in destructors, and so it can be done trivially with multiple return statements.

Comment: @jalf: Using RAII is _a choice_. You don't _have_ to use it. Anyway, the OP says - explicitly - that he has no resources to free.

Comment: Which is why is nice to have IF you are going to end up with said resources. It's a pattern I added to common use a while ago because I found my self copy pasting large chunks of little code to handle those cases and it removes that problem and is more descriptive than just return;

Comment: @Tomalak: shooting yourself in the foot is a choice too. So is writing buggy code. But RAII is a pretty fundamental aspect of *good* C++ code anno 2011. And it solves the only problem that could otherwise have led someone to prefer goto over multiple return statements

Comment: @jalf: RAII and `goto` are not mutually exclusive. In fact, the implications of their use are largely orthogonal. (But yes, of course one should use "best practices" where possible, my pedanticism aside :P)

Comment: @Tomalak: Of course they aren't. I never said they were. I said that RAII makes gotos unnecessary, but eliminating the one problem you might otherwise cause by having multiple return statements.

Comment: @jalf: Nothing's ever "necessary" at the end of the day, and to adopt a strategy of "I will only use features when it is necessary for me to do so, and I will otherwise spurn them with extreme prejudice" doesn't seem entirely productive; but OK. :)

Comment: I think a strategy of "I will not use features if they have no redeeming qualities whatsoever" has served me pretty well so far. If I have a choice between a tool that makes most readers of my code puke, *and which only makes my code more fragile*, versus one that, well, doesn't do that, then yes, I will spurn the former with extreme prejudice. And I'd argue that doing otherwise doesn't seem "entirely productive". In the same way that I spurn, with extreme prejudice, the practice of putting your foot into the mouth of an alligator when you go outside, because, well, a shoe just works better...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, its not advisable to use `goto`. It generates problems in readability of the code. Better use a `break;` statement where you want to leave the loop and return at the end of the code. That's the standard procedure.

```
while( get_input() )
{
    if( input == "somethingcool" )
    {
        if( !process_somethingcool() )
            break; // <-- a couple of these
    }
    //...
    else // bad input, error handling is fancier than this, but irrelevant to the question
        break; //although its better if you handle it somehow here.
}
return;
```

Comment: The legibility of `goto` is _just the same_ as the legibility of `return` in this use case. Stop repeating baseless dogma. I'd also love to see a citation for your term "standard procedure".

Comment: I'd love to see you use multiple goto with multiple labels and keep up with that. But I'm not going to advice it to someone. There's a reason why that `break` keyword exists.

Comment: @Bibhas: ... in _this_ use case. **Use the right tool for the job** instead of generalising. The fact that `break` does _exactly the same thing here_ as the OP's proposed use of `goto`, yet you don't even flinch at the possibility of using it, is remarkably telling.

Comment: Well, I see you already have experience with `goto`-bashing. So i'll restrain myself from going there. All the answers are here. Let the OP choose what he wants. And another thing, even if I follow your last comment, `break` is also the right tool for the job here(exactly same as they are)..

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: No, `goto` does not do the same thing as `break` here. There are some subtle differences in how C++ handles scoping and object lifetimes; `goto` violates that model and `break` does not.

Comment: @greyfade: `goto` won't jump over initialisations, and it doesn't prevent object destruction if you jump out of scope; or am I wrong with that last bit? It _has_ been a while since I went through the specifics.

Comment: @greyfade: See ruben's comment on your answer. `goto` does not violate the model at all. I think you're thinking of `longjmp`.

Comment: @Bibhas: I'm not disputing that `goto` probably isn't the best choice here; my answer says as much. :) I'm just averse to when someone reaches that conclusion through dogma rather than reason :P

Answer (score 0):

Why not structure your code using "guard clauses" (by reversing the logic) instead of the nested ifs. Then the whole question of using goto becomes moot.

```
while( get_input() )
{
    if( input != "somethingcool" )
    {
        return; //handle error
    }
    if( !process_somethingcool() )
        return; //handle error
    }
}
return; //success
```

Comment: I don't understand how this moots the question. Regardless, getting rid of the nested ifs is +1.

Comment: In my example, this does not get rid of nested `if`. I think you failed to see the `//...` which signifies lots more strings that could be input, making your construction above incorrect. And it does indeed not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  You should refactor the code into something readable
and maintainable.  Every case I've seen (and I've seen a lot)
where the programmer has needed a `goto`, and most of the cases
where he's needed multiple returns (and all cases where the
return has been nested in a loop) would have be better solved by
refactoring the code into separate, simpler functions, each of
which had a single return at the end of the function.  (Multiple
returns are sometimes justified for very simple functions; e.g.
I'll use them if the only statement in the function is
a `switch`, and every case ends with a `return`.)

Answer (score -1):

IMHO use multiple returns and do not use goto. Those who use goto, also set dogs on fire.

Comment: Really Hyperboreus? set dogs on fire?

Comment: Personally, I see goto statements in procedural or OO language only as legacy from their ancestors. Wild jumping around in your code does not really add to its readability and verifiability.

Comment: I beg to differ on this one, it allows you to handle abnormal function closure within the top level scope of the function and in a single location. Thus allowing for easier readability. I'm not saying that we should abandon other flow control in favour of goto but this is a case where it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr. Ack. And after all, it is also a question of personal preferences and choices.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr is right. Labels are often the right tool for a state machine that, say, parses strings.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: "Wild jumping around in your code"? Like, when you call a function, or invoke a constructor from a different TU? `goto` is actually pretty limited and doesn't let you "jump" as far as those other, completely normal programming conventions do.

Comment: A function call (even since ass times) is a different matter than an unconditioned jump.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: It's obviously not exactly the same language construct, but it's not that different. Your argument appeared originally to be about "jumping around in your code", but now that I've pointed out that widely-accepted conventions do this too, it's changed. I'm not really following. Oh well.

Comment: From (maybe my) philosophical point of view, a function (routine, method) is construct that receives a certain input, may have certain side effects and returns a certain output. You call it when you need the result or the side effect. This is the central point of procedural programming. The function itself, first does maybe some intialisation, some work and some cleanup, all in a defined order. A jump (conditioned or unconditioned) simply beams you to some place elsewhere without this structured behaviour. [cont...]

Comment: [...cont]. A function would be, you leave the highway at an exit, go to burgerking, queue up, order your menu, eat it and go back to the highway. A jump would be, you go on the highway and beam to the front of the lane at burger king (without initialising the local variable burgerking_waitingqueue). Appearing out of thin air in fornt of 20 people waiting for their Whopper will lead to trouble. But as I said, this is a philosophical question.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Sorry, but that's simply not true. `goto` is not `longjmp`; it does _not_ violate object cleanup. See 6.6/2 in the C++0x FDIS.

Comment: @Tomalak: lol, you should quote me, not copy my valuable lookup work `;)`

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for the info. UNfortunatly I have no c++ compiler at hand now. Could you tell me what happens in an environment like that: goto label; int a = 5; label: a++;

Comment: @Hyperboreus: [That's a compilation error](http://ideone.com/ROKE1). `goto` may not "jump" over object initialisation. (ideone.com and codepad.org eliminate the need for a local compiler for testing language features.) Interestingly, [you can jump over construction without initialisation](http://ideone.com/aD5T3), but it would be UB anyway to use the resulting value. Something like [this](http://ideone.com/PHRr0) is OK.

Comment: @Tomalak. Thank you, you quite abruptly changed my views on using goto. I think I was just too happy when I used my first C compiler that I didn't need to use jnz, jz, jmp etc anymore, and that "goto" called into memory bad experiences with backpack-asm-programming.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Hopefully I've demonstrated today that a lot of the `goto`-bashing is merely a result of uninformed [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt) [though, of course, not all of it]. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: But why does it say in your example "prog.cpp:4: warning: ‘a’ is used uninitialized in this function"? IMO, a shouldn't even exist in this scope. When was it declared and allocated?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: It does exist. The `goto` _does not affect the object's existence_. You can't just jump over declarations and make the thing they declare vanish from existence. The confusion here is that the object's existence isn't as dependent on a single line of procedural code (the declaration) as it looks like it is.

Comment: @Tomalak Does this mean that all variables of a given scope, are allocated when entering the scope, no matter where they are declared inside the scope? Like in {foo(); bar(); int a;}, a would plop into existence before foo() is called?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: It's unspecified precisely when they pop into existence. That's an implementation detail abstracted away from us by the language's very existence. Again, though, recall that you can't jump over initialisations: [your mindset is safe for complex objects](http://ideone.com/R0y0n).